# Why is my Google Cloud SQL instance being billed every hour?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

It seems like I'm being overbilled but I want to make sure I am not misunderstanding how [Per Use](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing) billing works. Here are the details:

- I'm running a small test PHP application on Google App Engine with no visitors other than myself every once in a while.
- I periodically reset the database via cron: originally every hour, then every 3 hours last month, now every 6 hours.
- Pricing plan: [Per Use](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing)
- Storage Used: 0.1% of 250 GB
- Type: First Generation
- IPv4 address: None
- File system replication: Synchronous
- Tier: D0
- Activation Policy: On demand

Here's the billing through the first 16 days of this months:

```
Google SQL Service  D0 usage - hour 383 hour(s) $9.57
```

16 days * 24 hours = 384 hours * $.025 = **$9.60** . So it appears I've been charged every hour this month. This also happened last month.

I understand that I am [charged the full hour for every part of an hour that the SQL instance is active](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#why_charged_more_than_uptime).

Still, with the minimal app usage and the database reset 4 times a day, I would expect the charges (even allowing for a couple extra hours of usage each day) to be closer to:

16 days * 6 hours = 80 hours * $.025 = **$2.40**.

Any explanation for the discrepency?

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://serverfault.com/tags/google-cloud-platform/info

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "resetting" your database? Do you have your activation policy set to "on demand"?

Comment: you might have lots of automated visitors, crawlers etc. Have you checked the logs?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood This crossed my mind. I did look at the activity graph on the dashboard and didn't see any activity for several hours. I didn't think to check the logs. I'll do so later when I have a chance.

Comment: Issue solved. My last 2 deploys apparently failed to update my `cron.yaml` file in production so my database reset job was still running hourly as I originally scheduled it. @PaulCollingwood, if you want to turn your comment into an answer and include the possibility of a task running more frequently than expected, I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks all for your attention and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs are the source of truth usually. Check them to see if you are being visited by an aggressive crawler, a stuck task that keeps retrying etc.

Or you may have a cron job that is running and performing work. You can view that in the "task queue/cron jobs" section in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

You might be have assigned an Ipv4 address to your instance and Google Developer Console clearly states

> You will be charged $0.01 each hour the instance is inactive and has an IPv4 address assigned.

This might be the reason of your extra bill.

Comment: Pretty sure I don't have an IPv4 address assigned. I'll double check later today as soon as I have a chance and add it as bullet point to question.